# Laravel foreach loop returning more results than correct

Tags: php, foreach, laravel, laravel-blade

My foreach loop should only return 1 result, however, it returns three, of the same!

I'm using Blade for the template -

> {{count($alerts)}}

returns '1'. But the foreach loop below:

```
@foreach($alerts as $alert)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $alerts->id }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The controller function passing the array of data is:

```
public function getIndex()
{

    $id     = Auth::user()->id;    
    $alert = Alert::find($id);      
    $this->layout->content = View::make('index', array('alerts' => $alert));

}
```

A DD($alert) also returns just 1 result.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: `<td>{{ $alerts->id }}</td>`: instead should be `<td>{{ $alert->id }}</td>`. Change `$alerts` -> `$alert`

Comment: Unfortunately, changing from $alerts to $alert returns this error - ErrorException - Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Alright, if you post us the code of `Alert` model class and content of `var_dump($alert)`, I will probably help you.

Comment: Also, your view might expect an array instead of just one object. So you should encase it in array: `View::make('index', array('alerts' => array($alert)));`

Comment: Encapsulating the $alert variable has corrected it. Thank you! I do have another foreach loop that works correctly (but it by default has more than 1 result). Was this error because of the 1 result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly answer your question, I will post solution here:

```
$alert = Alert::find($id);
```

Will return only 1 object which has a unique identifier e.g. `id`. It should never turn more than 1 object.

So, since your `view` has a `foreach` loop, it expects an array objects.
Thus if you know that you received only one object, just encase it in array:

```
View::make('index', array('alerts' => array($alert)));
```

However, some other methods like `Alert::all()` or others may already return an array of objects, because you request many of them. In this case, you do not need to encase it in arrays.